# Does the return function of useEffect run when the component is mounted?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

This is my code

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const PageOne = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
      return () => {console.log("PageOne")}
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <h1>PageOne</h1>
            <Link to="/two">Page two</Link>
        </>
    );
}
```

This is what I see in the console when visit PageOne

```
PageOne
```

This is what gets printed in the console when I navigate from PageOne to PageTwo (PageOne and PageTwo have the same structure)

```
PageOne
PageTwo
```

So I think that the return function defined in useEffect runs when the component is mounted and unmounted. I am using react-router-dom and Vite in this project.

Is this normal? And, does there exist a way to run a side-effect function only when a component will be unmounted?

Sorry if I made some mistakes. I am a new developer and an English student.

Comment: Could be React strict mode, which mounts components twice to achieve better error checking. https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Comment: yep, you can see some arguments for this behavior in this issue here https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24502#issuecomment-1121089680

Answer (score 3):

it happens is an intentional feature of the React.StrictMode. It only happens in development mode and should help to find accidental side effects in the render phase.

if you see [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
> can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions
> ...

Answer (score 1):

I think your question has been misunderstood but the explanations about `StrictMode` provided by the other users are correct.

Now, to answer what I think is your actual question: `useEffect`'s clean up function not only executes when your component is about to unmount, it also runs to clean up previous renders' effects before actually running the next scheduled effect.

Conclusion: Don't worry, this is a expected behaviour. I will leave the [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to React's docs where this is explained.